# How to sort an Array based on value in PHP without breaking Array structure

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to sort the array based on "match" index value as shown below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [U] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 10443
                    [match] => 100
                )

        )

)
```

This Array will be having match value like 25,50,75 etc.....

I tried below code but didn't worked :

```
function array_sort_by_column(&$arr, $col, $dir = SORT_ASC) {
    $sort_col = array();
    foreach ($arr as $key=> $row) {
        $sort_col[$key] = $row['U'][$col];
    }
    return array_multisort($sort_col, $dir, $arr);
}

$a_sl =$this->array_sort_by_column($a_sl, 'match');
```

where $a_sl contains array structure mentioned above.

How to sort this array based on match without breaking the Array structure.

Comment: but this code is not working for me...anyone has better solution....

Comment: Use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with a little self-written comparison function.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to sort arrays by subvalues:

```
function array_sort_subval($a, $subkey) {

  if (!is_array($a) || count($a) == 0) {
    return $a;
  }

  $i = 0; // Required to work around items with the same subkey value
  foreach($a as $k=>$v) {
    $b[$v[$subkey] . $i] = $v;
    $i++;
  }

  ksort($b);

  foreach($b as $key=>$val) {
    $c[] = $val;
  }

  return $c;

}
```

To sort on deeper elements of your array, simply change the line

```
$b[$v[$subkey] . $i] = $v;
```

to get the deeper $subkey you want to sort on.

Comment: And of course, if you need to sort numerically, you can add the SORT_NUMERIC flag to ksort